# Unable to complete installation using Bitnami

Tags: joomla-3.x, installation

When trying to install Joomla on a local host (OS X 10.10) using Bitnami, I get this error:

> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete
>   correctly Error running /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql
>   --user=root --host=localhost --socket="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock" --database=bitnami_joomla --password=**** -e "SOURCE /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apps/joomla/htdocs/installation/sql/mysql/joomla.sql;":
>   Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be
>   insecure. ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 14 in file:
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apps/joomla/htdocs/installation/sql/mysql/joomla.sql':
>   Table 'bitnami_joomla.jos_assets' doesn't exist

How do I fix this? (I'm obviously dead in the water!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple word of advice:

**Don't use 3rd party software that supposedly make installation easier**

I have never really seen the point in them. In addition to this, we can't really give supports for 3rd party software as it is nothing to do with us.

Joomla is extremely easy to install, even easier in the 3.x series, so I would suggest you [download the installation package](http://www.joomla.org/download.html) from the official site, extract it and go through the simple steps.

Comment: I'm a noob with Joomla (on my 2nd week now) and since my ISP is having problems I wanted to install on my local host.  I did download from the joomla.org site, but didn't find any instructions for installing on a local host.  Can you point me to a doc or something?  I would really, really appreciate it!  SD

Comment: @spokane-dude - check this article out: http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-mar-2013/item/1110-free-e-book-%E2%80%93-introducing-joomla-30-made-easy

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you... finally got it in the correct folder and I'm on my way... have a good evening... SD